# Unwanted event triggering on disabled controls in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a basic form that has different controls like buttons, trackbar,etc. During any event, I disable all my controls in the form using

```
void ChangeEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

and enable them back once I finish processing the data.

During the control disabled time, if I click on the trackbar or any other control that has an event handler, the corresponding event handler code gets executed when I enable my controls.

How can I avoid this event triggering?

Comment: Show the code that uses this function. it's probably because you are blocking the UI thread between disabling and enabling

Comment: Is it because I have a loop that waits for the processing to get completed ?

Comment: You didn't show the code, so i'm guessing here, but try to run the code in between in a background thread and await it.

Comment: My guess is what while processing data you are hanging UI for a duration (setting `Enabled` to false and then to true in one tight loop). In winforms you can *"solve"* the problem (notice sarcasm) by calling `DoEvents()` immediately after calling your `ChangeEnabled()`. Proper solution would be to organize processing without handing UI (task/thread/background worker + invoke).

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but is a tip: Dont loop all your controls to set enable property, just use an external container and chage enable property to this container. This will set Enable to all it's child controls.

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals Thank you for the tip.Is it a best practice to follow? Or Does it have any advantages over the looping method ?

Comment: It's better, faster, and over all things, the framework do it for you, with its own logic for looping the childs.